# How do you assign values from a linked list

Tags: c

I'm adding the next bit to this silly assignment of mine, and I'm modifying my old code now that I'm implementing these 'Linked List' things, but I can't figure out how you pull data out of them?

So, the software needs to pull the variables for whatever planet you're up to in the list, and assign the numbers to the variables, if that makes sense?

```
typedef struct Planet
{
    char Planet_Name[30];
    double Fuel;
    double Velocity;
    double Height;
    double Gravity;
    int Maximum_Thrust;
    double Difficulty;
}Planet_t;

typedef struct PlanetNode
{
    Planet_t* planet_Name;
    struct PlanetNode* next;
}PlanetNode_t;

typedef struct PlanetList
{
    PlanetNode_t* head;
    int count;
}PlanetList_t;
```

(in main)

```
PlanetList_t* SolarSystem = calloc(1, sizeof(PlanetList_t));

printf("The Planets are (with their corresponding difficulty level) 
Pluto[0], Moon[1], Mercury[2], Mars[3].....

double height = SolarSystem->head->Height;
double velocity = SolarSystem[PlanetNum]->Velocity;
double fuel = SolarSystem[PlanetNum]->Fuel;
double gravity = SolarSystem[PlanetNum]->Gravity;
double fuelBurn;
double difficulty = SolarSystem[PlanetNum]->Difficulty;
```

So basically, I need to figure out that last bit. Each iteration of the program changes the selected planet (linearly going through the planets), so the variables need to be renewed each time.

Comment: What do you mean by "pull data out of them"? Do you ask how to print all values in the whole list?

Comment: What do you mean by "pull the variables for whatever planet youre up to in the list"? How do you identify the "planet youre up to"? Do you have e.g. a pointer to it?

Comment: What do you mean by "assign the numbers to the variables"? Which numbers to which variables?

Comment: I think you need to spend more time on explaining what you want. Use more words. Use examples. Describe sequences "I am up to pluto, i.e. my thingy is containing the something of pluto. Then I want to pull the variable with plutos whatsit, which means I want to fooble it. Then I want to assign the voodoo number to the wicca variable of pluto."

Comment: Each planet has a name, a fuel, a velocity, a height, a gravity, and a difficulty associated with it.

I need to get those numbers, and assign them to those double variables within main.
Each iteration of the main loop requires that those double variables receive new values (from the next planet).

Im an idiot at this stuff and I didn't think that was a complex question? I just don't know how to write the code.

Comment: Could you make something close to a [mcve]? A program with hardcoded initialisation of three planets, which just prints all of their information for example.